# Render images from wordpress properly

Tags: wordpress, image, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic2

I have a ionic app in which I am displaying my wordpress posts. But the images of the wordpress posts are not displayed/rendered correctly. I am using the wordpress API to get my posts from the wordpress website.

Example - 
[image]

Template code snippet used for rendering the fetched wordpress post-

```
    <div *ngIf="selectedItem" class="selection">
       <h2 [innerHTML]="selectedItem.title.rendered"></h2>
       <p [innerHTML]="selectedItem.content.rendered" text-justify></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you checked that css isn't doing this? When you load the image up by itself in the browser (developer tools > inspect > right click image url > open in new tab) is it also stretched then?

Comment: @digout the image looks fine when opened in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this, was pretty simple and obvious -

Add the following scss code for that particular page -

```
img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
}
```